# How to use specific fields for specific application builds (debug/release)?

Tags: java, android, build, gradle

I use `gradle` to build my android project. When the build type is `Debug`, I want to change a boolean value in java file `Constans.java`.

```
public static final boolean IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT = false;
```

I use this value to control my app request different server. How to do that, I can't find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many fields as you want by editing your `build.gradle` file like this:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean","IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT","true"
        buildConfigField "boolean","SOME_OTHER_FIELD","false"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "boolean","IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT","true"
        buildConfigField "boolean","SOME_OTHER_FIELD","true"
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
```

For me however it would not at first recognize the field with

```
if (BuildConfig.IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT) {
    // Do something on Debug build
}
if (BuildConfig.SOME_OTHER_FIELD) {
    // Do something else
}
```

Rebuilding didn't help either. What helped was just simply restarting my AndroidStudio.

Comment: Do I need to create the BuildConfig.java file at my project root directory?

Comment: @user3932202 BuildConfig is created by the ADT, so you shouldn't have to import/create it yourself. Although now that I look at it, there's already a DEBUG boolean field which you can use. Updated the answer.

Comment: THX.I have one more question, I want to use more boolean value,so ,I am going to add a boolean value in BuildConfig, but it prompt that "Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY". What can I do ? I want one more boolean value;

Comment: @user3932202 you can add multiple fields in the way I shown. By the way using BuildConfig.DEBUG is reported to be buggy at times, so you may want to stay away from that.

Comment: You mean I can use other boolean fields that I added in BuildConfig like "IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT",but do not use the  BuildConfig.DEBUG?

Comment: @user3932202 Either research the DEBUG field further or don't use it. I've read it can cause some problems. You can add multiple fields like in my example.

Comment: if I use the field like "if (BuildConfig.IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT)" , the eclipse will prompt that "IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT cannot be resolved or is not a field",do I create the field of the manual in gen/.../BuildConfig.java

Comment: @user3932202 as I've said I had a similar problem with android studio. Try restarting and/or rebuilding your project.

Comment: I restarting and rebuilding my eclipse , but it does not works,it always say "cannot be resolved or is not a field".If eclipse can not use it like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own build variables:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {

        buildConfigField "boolean","IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT","false"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!But my boolean value "IS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT" is not in buildConfig. It was in Constans.java . How can I do? By the way ,I want to know that where could find the document about this. How do you know the solution?

Comment: Have a look at this post http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/.